# Copy data from one database to another - referenced tables and identities included

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database with this two tables :

[OldDb].[Per].[Person]

```
PersonId | FirstName | LastName | Code
2003     | 'Mike'    | 'Jordan' | 2
2357     | 'Sara'    | 'Jacobs' | 1
3481     | 'John'    | 'Gates'  | 5
```

[OldDb].[Sal].[Customer]

```
CustomerId | PersonId | CustomerType
830        | 2003     | 3
945        | 2357     | 2
1333       | 3481     | 2
```

And my new database with same tables and schema :

[NewDb].[Per].[Person]

```
PersonId | FirstName | LastName | Code
```

[NewDb].[Sal].[Customer]

```
CustomerId | PersonId | CustomerType
```

PersonId in table Person is identity and I can use this code to copy people but PersonId's will be different from old database so I can't use the second query I said below to copy data from customer table.

```
INSERT INTO NewDb.per.Person
(FirstName,LastName,Code)
SELECT FirstName,LastName,Code
FROM OldDb.per.Person


INSERT INTO NewDb.Sal.Customer
(PersonId,CustomerType)
SELECT PersonId,CustomerType
FROM OldDb.Sal.Customer
```

Now I want a query so I can copy data to new db for both tables.

Any help would be a great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your old data  exist on `new db`? Do you only want to insert, or both insert and update?

Comment: NewDb is empty and I want copy all data from OldDb.

Comment: With old `person id`?

Comment: I don't care about old personId, I just want the PersonId I added in newdb, be the same PersonId that will inserted in NewDb , Table : Customer. because when the PersonId is changed in person table. old personId is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new database is empty, if you want to keep your old `PersonId`, you could use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT NewDb.per.Person ON`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT NewDb.per.Person ON  -- then you could use personId in Insert
INSERT INTO NewDb.per.Person
(PersonId, FirstName,LastName,Code)
SELECT PersonId, FirstName,LastName,Code
FROM OldDb.per.Person

SET IDENTITY_INSERT NewDb.per.Person OFF  -- remember set it off after insert

-- then insert new Customer without conflict
INSERT INTO NewDb.Sal.Customer
(PersonId,CustomerType)
SELECT PersonId,CustomerType
FROM OldDb.Sal.Custome
```

Reference link: [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql)

And if you want new `PersonId` auto increment you could do this:

```
 ----CREATE `OldPersonId` column  in your NewDb.per.Person

INSERT INTO NewDb.per.Person
(OldPersonId, FirstName,LastName,Code)
SELECT PersonId, FirstName,LastName,Code
FROM OldDb.per.Person

-- You could insert you new customer Inner join by `OldPersonId` Column
INSERT INTO NewDb.Sal.Customer
(PersonId,CustomerType)
SELECT np.PersonId,CustomerType
FROM OldDb.Sal.Customer oc
INNER JOIN NewDb.per.Person np ON oc.PersonId = np.OldPersonId

-----DELETE `OldPersonId` column in NewDb.per.Person
```

Comment: Thank you this one worked for me. I was trying to handle other conflicts in database. Big databases, big problems xD.